# How to combine dynamically created fields with standard django form?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, forms

I  use simple  django form

```
class MassPaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = LeasePayment

        fields = ['payment_type', 'is_deposit',  'amount', 'method', 'payment_date', 'description']
```

On my template I have created few chained dropdowns using AJAX

```
      <form method="POST"  class="form" action="" method="get">
        <div class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <br><br>
            <b>Building:</b><br>
                <select name="building" id="building" onchange="getunit();">
  <option id="-1">Select building</option>
</select>


<br>
<b>Unit:</b><br>
<select name="unit" id="unit" onchange="getlease();">
  <option id="-1">Select unit</option>
</select>
  <br>
<b>Lease:</b><br>
 <select name="lease" id="lease" onchange="getleaseterm()">
  <option id="-1">Select lease</option>
</select>
  <br>
<b>Term:</b><br>
   <select name="leaseterm" id="leaseterm">
  <option id="-1">Select lease term</option>
</select> 
            {{ form|crispy}}



        {{ form.media }}

            <BR><BR>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary">Save</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

I need 'lease' and 'leaseterm' to be part of my form when it saves since they are mandatory fields in the model..
How can I include those AJAx dynamically generated dropdown as part of  my Django form?

Comment: Just add them to your form directly (not in `Meta` if they're not part of your model): `unit = CharField()` etc... That way when you initialise your form using the `request.POST` data, these fields will pick up the values posted. You can then use the `form.cleaned_data['unit']` in your view to save it somewhere.

Comment: You'll also need to add the form fields to your template explicitly instead of using `{{ form }}`. Or you can add a custom CSS attribute like `hide` so that the automatically generated HTML field is not rendered, since you're adding them manually already.

Answer (score 1):

Just add them to your form directly, if they're part of your model. Or if the model fields default to something that doesn't work for validation, override them directly as standard form fields. Since you're rendering them explicitly in your HTML, you don't want them to render. So you should add a css class to the widget to hide them from the browser (remove them entirely with javascript), otherwise you'll have two input fields with the same name.

```
class MassPaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    unit = CharField(widget=HiddenInput(attrs={'class': 'to-remove'})
    lease = CharField(widget=HiddenInput(attrs={'class': 'to-remove'})
    leaseterm = CharField(required=False, widget=HiddenInput(attrs={'class': 'to-remove'})  # just as an example

    class Meta:
         # rest of Meta class here
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain more what do you mean by rendering? 
I was I able to combine it visually. So I beleive now I have this rendering owerright issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392885/dynamically-build-ajax-dropdown-resets-to-original-state-when-trying-to-save-wit