# Dynamically build AJAX dropdown resets to original state when trying to save with django form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I my form I have few dropdowns chained between them with AJAX.

This is how I a populating them

```
    function getleaseterm() {

        //get a reference to the select element
        $select = $('#id_leaseterm');
        //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
        var l_id = ($("select[name='lease'] option:selected").attr('value'));
        //var l_id = 13;
        l_url = "/api/get_leaseterm/"+l_id+"/";

        $.ajax({
          url: l_url,
          dataType:'JSON',
          success:function(data1){
            //clear the current content of the select
            $select.empty();
            $select.append('<option value="-1">Select term </option>');
            //iterate over the data and append a select option

            $.each(data1, function(key, val){
              $select.append('<option value="' + val.id + '">' + val.as_char + '</option>');
            })
          },

        });

}
```

And this is the control

```
<select class="select" id="id_leaseterm" name="leaseterm">
<option value="-1" selected="selected">-----</option>
</select>
```

It all works , I am changing values in my dropdowns and options of other dropdowns are updated.So I can select the relevant value.

The problem is when I  Save the for -  the form gets not the value that I have put there but the default value that was there before any manipulation of Ajax have been done.

Also when I do view source I see in the code is default value and not what was selected from what I have build with AJAX.(Even that on the screen I do see the correct values in the select options...)

My backend is Django .
My Django form formatted in following way.

```
class MassPaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    leaseterm = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=LeaseTerm.objects.none()) # Need to populate this using jquery
    lease= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Lease.objects.none()) # Need to populate this using jquery
    class Meta:
        model = LeasePayment

        fields = ['lease', 'leaseterm', 'payment_type', 'is_deposit',  'amount', 'method', 'payment_date', 'description']
```

What could be the problem ? And any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Please check the HTML source of your page (in your browser) and make sure you have only one `<select>` element with id `id_leaseterm`. Since you're not showing us your template, that might be an issue.

Comment: Also the best way to debug these issues is to actually inspect the data that gets posted (by setting a breakpoint in your django view after `def post(self):`) to check what your form is submitting.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what was the problem 
it is in my form file

If I keep the lease and leaseterm fields just in Meta class that it doesn't reset those fields on submit any more . And all my logic finally works as designed.

```
class MassPaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = LeasePayment

        fields = ['lease', 'leaseterm', 'payment_type', 'is_deposit',  'amount', 'method', 'payment_date', 'description']
```